# page level and element scrollbar

Tags: html, css

Following is fiddle: http://plnkr.co/edit/peQEGK4mNiPBqlknrO6V?p=preview

code is :

```
 <div id="navBar">
<nav id="nav" class="side-nav">
    <!--<ul>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menuitem 6</a></li>-->
        <ul id="nav-contain" aria-live="polite" title="navigation menu" tabindex="-1">
     <li class="menu-home main-menu closed">
        <a href="#"  >
           <p >Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed" >
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed" >
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" >
           <p>Menu</p>
        </a>
        <ul class="expand" >
           <li class="main-menu" >
              <a href="#">
                 <p>Menu</p>
              </a>

           </li>

  </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
     <li class="main-menu closed">
        <a href="#" >
           <p>Menu Level 1</p>
        </a>

     </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
</div>
```

If we look at output there are 2 scrolls one is page level scroll and other is element level scroll. I want only one scroll bar that is page level scroll.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
#viewport 
{ 
      min-height: 100%;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
}
```

Remove position property from this css id.

Comment: Have you tried removing position property? I just tested from the plunker link you send and it is tested

Comment: i just did this : 
#viewport {
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  
  width: 100%;
}
with your code

Comment: Oh - just tested it on chrome. might have browser compatibility issue. Will get back to you with a fix. one moment

Comment: i tried removing position & tested in chrome bt its not working

Comment: Try setting - position:fixed of #viewport. This should work, tested on chrome and IE.

Comment: it worked, but after that its not scrolling properly